# Select the previously-selected window in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I need an emacs built-in function or elisp function that can take me to the previously-selected window.  I thought that `(select-window (get-lru-window))` would do it, but if I run it several times, seems to just cycle between windows instead of swapping back and forth between them, which is what I expect.

Any other ideas?

Comment: The documentation for select-window says 'Optional second arg NORECORD non-nil means do not put this buffer at the front of the list of recently selected ones.' ... but that sounds backwards from what you're describing...

Comment: I think you can (ab)use the buffer list. Something like (select-window (buffer-window (other-buffer (current-buffer) t)))

Comment: Perfect, @AndersWaldenborg --  It's hacktacular, but it works just fine for my purposes.  Thanks!

Comment: Now if there only was a promote-this-comment-to-an-answer feature :)

Comment: Well, go ahead and post it as an answer and I'll accept it.  I'm actually surprised there isn't something more direct, but I'll take it!

Comment: Al Parker wrote a function that keeps track of buffers associated with frames that stores the list as part of the frame parameters.  It should be possible to use the same concept to keep track of the order of windows visited by prepending to the list and then looking for the car thereof to get the previous window.  A decision would need to be made regarding when prepending occurs which would constitute a previously selected window.  This would be a custom window list based on predefined criteria.  See Frame-Bufs for some ideas on how this might work:  https://github.com/alpaker/Frame-Bufs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to get the most recently selected window in emacs (as opposed to the least recently used returned by get-lru-window). Internally emacs tracks use_time on windows, and get-lru-window uses that to find the "oldest" window. But unfortunately that is not exposed in elisp.

The window list is ordered in [cyclic window ordering](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Cyclic-Window-Ordering.html) which doesn't help in your case.

The buffer-list is however ordered most-to-least recently used buffer (or not really strictly, there is a (bury-buffer) function to move a buffer last).

This means that, if you can transform your problem into something like "how can I switch to the buffer in a different window that was most recently the selected buffer", it should be possible.

One way would be to do something like this:

```
(defun switch-to-previous-buffer-in-a-different-window ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((otherbuf (other-buffer (current-buffer) t))
     (otherwin (get-buffer-window otherbuf)))
(if otherwin
    (select-window otherwin)
  (message "Last buffer (%s) is not currently visible" (buffer-name otherbuf)))))
```

Or the shorter, and more featureful:

```
(defun switch-to-previous-buffer-possibly-creating-new-window ()
  (interactive)
  (pop-to-buffer (other-buffer (current-buffer) t)))
```

Here `other-buffer` is used to get the most recently used buffer (except current-buffer). This should work fine as long as you don't switch buffers in the windows, because then other-buffer will no longer return the buffer in the other window, but the buffer you switched from in current window.

So instead of using other-buffer lets walk the buffer-list ourself to find the best candidate:

```
(defun switch-to-the-window-that-displays-the-most-recently-selected-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((buflist (buffer-list (selected-frame)))      ; get buffer list in this frames ordered
     (buflist (delq (current-buffer) buflist))     ; if there are multiple windows showing same buffer.
     (winlist (mapcar 'get-buffer-window buflist)) ; buf->win
     (winlist (delq nil winlist))                  ; remove non displayed windows
     (winlist (delq (selected-window) winlist)))   ; remove current-window
(if winlist
    (select-window (car winlist))
  (message "Couldn't find a suitable window to switch to"))))
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If the last window switch was done programmatically, then it is possible to select the previously selected window.

```
(defun your-function ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((sw (selected-window)))
    (do-something-useful-and-switch-window)
    (select-window sw)))
```

If the last window switch was done manually, then it should be possible to overload the window switching command to update a global list of window selection order, which is then used to switch back.

Answer (score 1):

`get-mru-window` with the third argument non-nil returns the previously selected window (see the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Cyclic-Window-Ordering.html#index-get_002dmru_002dwindow)).

```lisp
(defun my-select-last-window ()
  "Switch to the previously selected window."
  (interactive)
  (select-window (or (get-mru-window t t t)
                     (user-error "No other window to select"))))
```

Comment: Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].